# $wpdb variable throw this error Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in

Tags: database, wpdb, errors

I've this error "Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in"
from this code:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $folder . '/wp-config.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  $folder . '/wp-load.php');
if (!$wpdb) {
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
} else {
    global $wpdb;
}

function vendorDatails( $param)
{
    if ((substr ($param, 0, 0)) == '#')
    {
        substr($param, 1);
    }

    $order_ids = $wpdb->get_results( 
                                    "
                                     SELECT DISTINCT vendor_id 
                                     FROM $wpdb->lqrhxf_pv_commission 
                                     WHERE order_id = %d
                                    ",
                                        $param
                                );

    foreach ( $order_ids as $order_id )
    {
        echo $order_id->vendor_id;
    }
}
```

The db parameters are loaded successfully but I've the error on the line above when I use $wpdb variable:

```
 $order_ids = $wpdb->get_results(
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [PHP variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue, there is no `$wpdb` defined in your function.

Add

```
global $wpdb;
```

before trying to use the `$wpdb` object.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to use WordPress' functionality outside of WordPress you can use

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );
Then you can use WordPress's functionality. Check This. If you want to just access the database functions then

require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
if (!$wpdb) {
    $wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
} else {
    global $wpdb;
}

Comment: Isn't the second one exactly what OP had already done? (except with an extra `.$folder.` in the path). By the way you can use the {} button in the editor to format lines as code (which is just indenting them by four spaces)